# Accurate Y positioning in crystal reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

If i select the size and position of the object (textbox) in crystal reports 2008 , to set he x and y position. The X position is set in the accurate poition but the Y position is not set. The Y position slightly changes from what i set actually. Eg : x:5.25 ang y=0.07 after I saved, it automatically repositions the y axis to 0.083

Comment: Try checking File -> Options -> Layouts and see if "Snap To Grid" is selected.